# Custom Liferay service function failing to openSession()

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, portal

This problem has been frustrating me for quite some time and I'm hoping someone can help me out here.  I am using Service Builder to expose a custom entity to the JSON Web Service API, which I want to use in my portlet.  I cannot use Dynamic Queries, and since there will be several more complicated queries later on with multiple joins, I feel custom sql is the best option.  However, I'm not even able to begin the query because the call to openSession() throws a NPE.  Here's my code (I apologize for the length, but I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong here and I'm just trying to include everything that's relevant):

ServiceImpl class:

```
@JSONWebService
public class MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeServiceImpl extends MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeServiceBaseImpl {
    @Override
    public List<MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrime> getMessagesAsDiscussionPrime() throws SystemException {
        MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeFinder finder = new MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeFinderImpl();
        return finder.findByGroupId();
    }
}
```

My FinderImpl class:

```
public class MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeFinderImpl extends BasePersistenceImpl<MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrime> implements MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeFinder {

    @Override
    public List<MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrime> findByGroupId() throws SystemException {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate("liferaySessionFactory");

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession(); //exception here

            //other stuff here, eventually...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SystemException(e);
        } finally {
            closeSession(session); //throws NPE here
        }
    }
}
```

custom query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<custom-sql>
    <sql
        id="com.test.portlet.service.persistence.MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeFinder.findByGroupId">
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT * FROM MBMessage, MBThread
            WHERE
                (MBMessage.threadId = MBThread.threadId) AND
                (MBThread.groupID = ?) 
            ORDER BY
                MBThread.rootMessageId DESC, MBMessage.messageId ASC
        ]]>
    </sql>    
</custom-sql>
```

and service.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC
"-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.1.0//EN"
"http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_1_0.dtd">

<service-builder package-path="com.test.portlet">
    <namespace>MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrime</namespace>

    <entity name="MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrime" uuid="true" local-service="true" remote-service="true">

        <column name="messageId" type="long" primary="true" />
        <column name="threadId" type="long"/>
        <column name="userId" type="long"/>
        <column name="userName" type="String"/>
        <column name="body" type="String"/>

        <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.messageboards" entity="MBMessage" />
        <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.messageboards" entity="MBThread" />
    </entity>    
</service-builder>
```

The service function is visible from localhost:8080/custom-query-portlet/api/jsonws, which is where I'm calling it from.  Is there something in particular I need to do since this is being called remotely, besides setting @JSONWebService on the ServiceImpl class?  Please, someone help me out on this.  It's driving me up a wall!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 @Override
    public List<MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrime> findByGroupId() throws SystemException {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = openSession();

            //other stuff here, eventually...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SystemException(e);
        } 
    }
```

HTH

Comment: are you getting error while opening a session or inside finally block?

Comment: The openSession() call throws an exception.  The finally block attempts to close the session, which throws another exception (the NPE, since the session object is still null), which is not caught.  So that is where it technically errors out, but the underlying issue is that openSession() fails.

Answer (score 0):

Using Liferay 6.1.20 and for the build I used maven with Liferay Plugin Version 6.2.10.9.

Make sure your MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeFinderImpl class is in your service.persistence package/folder.

When the service builder is run it generates the interface for your WhateverFinderImpl.  In your case MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeFinderImpl.  Additionally it adds code to instantiate it into your WhateverLocalServiceImpl.  In your case it seems to be MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeServiceImpl.

If your MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeServiceImpl class is equivalent to the WhateverLocalServiceImpl then it should already have your MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeFinderImpl class instantiated within it and you can change your code to following and it will work.

```
@JSONWebService
public class MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeServiceImpl extends MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeServiceBaseImpl {
    @Override
    public List<MBMessagesAsDiscussionPrime> getMessagesAsDiscussionPrime() throws SystemException {
        return mBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeFinder.findByGroupId();
    }
}
```

The camel case might be different for mBMessagesAsDiscussionPrimeFinder.

Comment: you would use session = openSession();  like the other answerer suggest.